# How can I dampen current spikes when using NPNs to drive an LED

Tags: 555, npn, led-driver

Hi I have the following circuit, its purpose is to flash an LED once per second. I'm using a pair of transistors as a constant current source but I observe current spikes of 20% or so when it is simulated. Can anyone explain why this occurs and how to resolve it.

[image: My Circuit]

Thank you very much for your help! As suggested by The Photon and Bimpelrekkie I tried using a small cap on the collector-emitter of Q2 and it completely removes the spikes - perfect

[image: With capacitor on collector-emitter of Q2]

Comment: Do plot the currents of all other components (C1, C2, R1, R4, etc) and you likely find the source. Then, consider how the 555 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing current through the parasitic capacitance of the diode.

You could avoid it by turning on the transistor more slowly.

But you shouldn't really expect this simulation to be predictive of what you'll see in a real circuit, since your LED is not likely to have same parasitic capacitance as a 1N914. Also the power source you use in the real world will have parasitic resistance and inductance that will reduce the overshoot current.

Comment: *...by turning on the transistor more slowly.* You could try adding a capacitor across the collector-emitter of Q2 to do that. I'd start with a 100 nF capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to The Photon's answer I wouldn't be surprised is a simulator error too.

- 555 OUT switches high biasing Q1 hard on.
- Current rises in R3 and the voltage across it rises until Q2 starts to turn on.
- Q2 steals the bias from Q1 tending turning it off.
- The circuit quickly stabilises so that there is about 0.7 V across R3 which results in \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {0.7}{35} = 20 \ \text {mA} \$.

In real life the 555 OUT will have a certain slew rate (rate of change of output voltage) and unless there is a poor circuit layout Q1 and Q2 should be able to respond to this without the overshoot.

Comment: Thanks you help me understand the circuit much more clearly